# Python requests image upload returns error 500 but curl command works

Tags: python-3.x, image, curl, python-requests

I'm trying to connect to an API Endpoint to upload an image file (python3.6 & requests).

The upload needs to be authorised, which is achieved via an auth-token. I've successfully tested the API with both Postman and cURL. The working cURL command is:

```
curl -X POST 'https://example.com/api/upload'
-H 'Accept: application/json'
-H 'Authorization: bearer <TOKEN>
-F 'image=@19JA_slingua_IMG_3798-1600x800.jpg'
```

which results in the response:

```
200 OK
{"data":{"id":"<image ID>","type":"image"}}
```

My python code using the requests library basically looks as follows:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'bearer <TOKEN>',
}

files = {
    'image': ('19JA_slingua_IMG_3798-1600x800.jpg', 
     open('19JA_slingua_IMG_3798-1600x800.jpg', 'rb')),  
}  

response = requests.post('https://example.com/api/upload', 
                          headers=headers, files=files)
```

This however returns a **500 Internal Server Error**.

I've checked the prepared request, which looks as follows

```
POST https://example.com/api/upload
Authorization: bearer <TOKEN>
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_13_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100
Safari/537.36
Accept: application / json
Content-Length: 585218
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=d5c1db2b1bcb448b8e9e6fe852402a90

b'--d5c1db2b1bcb448b8e9e6fe852402a90\r\nContent-Disposition: form-
data; name="image"; filename="19JA_slingua_IMG_3798-
1600x800.jpg"\r\n\r\n\xff\xd8\xff\xe0\x00\x10JFIF\x00\x01\x01\x00\x00\x01\
x00\x01\x00\x00\xff\xdb\x00\x84\x00\x02\x01\x01\x01\x01\x01\x02\x01\x01\x0
 1\x02\x02\x02\x02\x02\x04\x03\x02\x02\x02\x02\x05\x04\x04\x03\x04\x06\x05\
x06\x06\x06\x05\x06\x06\x06\
```

I've hit a wall as to what to do in order to trouble shoot.

EDIT:

I've solved the problem by including the content-type (MIME-Type) in the request. This may be specific to the server.

```
import requests  

img_path = 'path/to/img.jpg'

headers = {'Authorization': 'bearer %s' % TOKEN,
           'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_14_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36',
           'Accept': 'application/transit+json',
           }
files = {'image': (img_path.split('/')[-1], open(img_path, 'rb'), 'image/jpeg')}

response = requests.post(ENDPOINT_URL, files=files, headers=headers)
```

Thanks for all the support!

Comment: In Postman you can click "code" on the right side (underneath of Save) and then under the dropdown you can select Python>Requests instead of HTTP. This should give you working Python Requests code that you can compare to the code that you wrote.

Comment: I tested on  (python3.6 & requests). I have difference on my request . `name="image"` not `name="19JA_slingua_IMG_3798-1600x800.jpg"` . btw using `--trace-ascii 1.txt` to check your curl request

Comment: @BigGerman. Postman generates similar code, but embeds the file in a multipart encoded data section (hard coded). AFAIK, this does not conform with requests documentation or best practices:

```payload = "------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW\r\nContent-Disposition: form-data; name=\"image\"\r\n\r\n\r\n------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4YWxkTrZu0gW--"

response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)```

Comment: @kcorlidy, thanks. You are right about the ```name="image"``` part of course. I had piped the verbose cURL output to a file to examine it. The only obvious differences where the lacking ```---------``` for the boundary tag, as well as the ```b'``` in front of the body. 

I'm wondering if that's a binary flag that should occur before the file transfer rather than the body tags.

Comment: @BigGerman, copy&pasting the postman code btw, results in an identical server error...

Comment: @kcorlidy, you mention you tested with python3.6 and requests. Was your test successful?

Comment: @MarkHallbauer i do not have the url, are you sure the url is `https://example.com/api/upload`?

Comment: @kcorlidy, the url is not example.com (I can't share the actual API and auth credentials here).   

I've solved the problem by experimentation; the issue was that I wasn't passing along the content-type (MIME-Type) of the file. See modified request code in EDIT of question.